# Hyphen not allowing jQuery AJAX call to work properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

**Problem:** The parameter being passed through my `addData()` function has a hyphen in it; think "12345678-9". Whenever the data being passed has a hyphen, I get the `Ajax Fail!` alert box popped up on my app. However, whenever I hardcode the `$_GET` variable to be a string or number without a hyphen, this part of my app works. I've narrowed it down to the likely fact that the hyphen is causing this error. See code below.

---

**HTML**

---

```
<button id="add-analysis-button" onClick="addData( $( '#click-number' ).text() )">Add Data</button>
```

**Javascript/jQuery/AJAX**

---

```
function addData(a_ship) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'models/add-data.php?oShip=' + a_ship,
    mimeType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert( data );
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Ajax Fail!');
    }
});
```

**PHP (File: add-data.php)**

---

```
<?php
echo $_GET['oShip'];
```

---

**What I've tried:** I have tried using javascript's replace function in `addData()` function to replace the hyphen with an HTML number. Eg: `a_ship = a_ship.replace('-', '&#45;')`. This seems to allow the code to partially work, but then gets rid of the number after the hyphen, which leads me into another problem.

**Question:**How do I pass hyphens from to jQuery's AJAX without causing error?

Comment: The problem is probably in the returned JSON. What does it look like when the call fails?

Comment: try : `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: When the call fails, I get the alert box that says "Ajax Fail!".

Comment: @aCarella no I mean what does the actual HTTP response look like?

Comment: @CodeGodie the "-" character does not have to be URI encoded.

Comment: @Pointy I understand, however, the issue may be something else rather than the dash. By trying `encodeURIComponent`, youd be ruling that out.

Comment: @CodeGodie yes that's true; it's not really robust code without it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. I tried `encodeURIcomponent' on my a_ship parameter, but that did not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you setting your MimeType to JSON. It should be `contentType`

Comment: What is the value of a_ship before ajax call. Use console.log(a_ship);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
mimeType: 'json',
```

to this:

```
contentType: 'json',
```

-Or-

removing mimeType altogether will solve this issue.

Comment: I was able to solve this before I saw your response, but trying your code worked as well. Marking this as the correct answer, and editing your response to include what worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this and reply back with the results (editable fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/caLu0kj9/).  Note the addition of the `dataType` in the ajax request and removal of the `onclick` event in the HTML code.

HTML:

```
<div id="click-number">12345678-9</div>
<button id="add-analysis-button">Add Data</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#add-analysis-button").click(function(){
    addData($( '#click-number').text());
});

function addData(a_ship) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'models/add-data.php?oShip=' + encodeURIComponent(a_ship),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            jqXHR.url = settings.url;
        },
        success: function(jqXHR, data) {
            alert("SUCCESS! " + data + " " + jqXHR.url);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            alert("FAIL! " + jqXHR.url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This does not work either, but I was able to get a couple of ideas from this post.